# Is it possible to dope Ca ions in an NaCl crystal to produce a vacancy defect?

Tags: physical-chemistry, inorganic-chemistry

I was just reading about defects and doping in solids and read about the defect in  ionic crystal ($\ce{NaCl}$). There were examples of $\ce{SrCl2}$. Could this also occur with $\ce{CaCl2}$?

Comment: Absolutely. If you analyze even "pure" NaCl you'll find all sorts of trace amounts of other cations and anions. The defect is of course caused by the +2 charge on a calcium ion, whereas the lattice wants a +1 charge. Not sure about the relative size of the ions which can cause disruptions in the lattice too.

Answer (score 1):

A peek at the NaCl - CaCl2 phase diagram (say at [FactSage](http://www.factsage.cn/fact/phase_diagram.php?file=CaCl2-NaCl.jpg&dir=FTsalt)) will show you that NaCl can hold quite a reasonable fraction of CaCl2 in the NaCl crystal. In contrast, CaCl2 has very limited to no solubility of NaCl.